# how to show square brackets and parentheses symbol correctly in mac terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, keyboard, keyboard-layout

how to show square brackets and parentheses symbol correctly in mac terminal?

when I type `{`  become `¨`  ,  `}` > `¼`, `[` > `ÿ`, `]` > `¦`  why and how to solve this?

Comment: This is likely an encoding issue. Your keyboard or locale may be set differently than you expect in the OS itself or Terminal preferences. If that doesn't help, consider asking on superuser.com.

Comment: thanks for reply I check the Terminal preference I can't find something wrong I do accept utf8 and english , and my OS is english too

Answer (score 1):

I have a Spanish keyboard, and have the same problem on Terminal. Instead of using Unicode UTF-8 in Terminal > Preferences > Profiles > Advanced > International > Text Encoding, I switched to Western (Windows Latin 1) and now all symbols coincide with my keyboard, i.o.w. I can type square bracket, etc. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck the Terminal setting `Edit --> Use Option-key as meta key`. That should solve the problem.

Remember to set this default in your profile: 
`Terminal --> Settings --> Profiles --> Keyboard --> Use Option-key as meta key`

Comment: Does not solve it - I get strange chars recently when trying to get brackts with `altgr`+7or8or9or0 - I closed the strange terminal and now it works.